# How to avoid manual duplication of documentation of types in interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I often have function signatures saved as a separate type when I use them in a lot of places.

The problem is, whenever I use such a type in an interface or a compound type, it doesn't automatically show me the documentation for the underlying type when hovering over the property...

```
/**
 * Documentation for function that is used in multiple places
 */
export type MyFunction = () => void

export interface SomeInferface {
  /**
   * I HAVE to duplicate the documentation manually here, if not, it won't show up in the interface...
   */
  myFunction: MyFunction
}

export type SomeType = {
  /**
   * I HAVE to duplicate the documentation manually here, if not, it won't show up in the type...
   */
  myFunction: MyFunction
}
```

This makes it veeeery un-user-friendly for devs who consume my libraries. So to mitigate that I have to **manually duplicate the documentation block of the type inside every interface and compound type that uses it!**

But this in turn is very error-prone if I change it and forget to update it somewhere...

How can I automatically have VSCode show the type documentation in the interfaces and compound types?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37876) that tracks including the documentation from value's type when you hover over that value

However what VS Code does today is expected as you are documenting two different things. In the example:

```
/**
 * Documentation for function that is used in multiple places
 */
export type MyFunction = () => void
```

The documentation is for `MyFunction` type.

However for:

```
export interface SomeInferface {
  /**
   * I HAVE to duplicate the documentation manually here, if not, it won't show up in the interface...
   */
  myFunction: MyFunction
}
```

the documentation is for the property `myFunction`.

In general, you should have different documentation for the property itself than for the type of that property

Comment: weird, because in all cases I have so far, adding documentation to my function types, I want the same documentation by default in the interfaces. So I believe when you say "you should have different documentation", is really just your opinion, and I beg to differ that there might be many with the same opinion as me as well. No offence meant!

Comment: The documentation for a type should document the type. The documentation for a property should document the property. If the documentation for these two is the same, it is usually a good sign something is wrong. Further, intellisense engines / docs generators let users navigate from a property to the type of that property. VS code for example has `go to type definition` that navigates right to the type of the property

Comment: interesting. I still beg to differ, and here is some perspective on my use case: I often pass a payload to an function in "object" form, it's basically a bunch of types I bundle for the payload of that function. Therefore, when using this similar payload object in multiple places I'd want to have it as its own interface. In this case there's absolutely no need for other documentation, so manual duplication of documentation is required. I know that You can click through / look at the underlying documentation of course, but that's besides the point.

Comment: If that is your goal, instead of duplicating a property in multiple places, you should express this in your code using inheritance or composition. Then you'd add documentation to a single property and that documentation will be shared everywhere that property is used

Answer (score 0):

After searching long for this everywhere, it would appear that this is not yet possible.
It's an open feature request:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37876